# PHP sort positions with null values but maintain structure

Tags: php

I'd like to sort an array with values that may or not exist in the database and the order structure should be respected.

Structure by default (positions from 1 to 5):

```
Amazon | Google | Ebay | Microsoft | Alibaba
```

This structure is initialized in PHP this way:

```
$data = 
[
    'Amazon'    => ['position' => null],
    'Google'    => ['position' => null],
    'Ebay'      => ['position' => null],
    'Microsoft' => ['position' => null],
    'Alibaba'   => ['position' => null]
];
```

**Important**: The positions stored in the database are always equal or bigger than 1.

Lets say Google has the position 1 and Alibaba 4 in the database:

```
$data['Google']['position'] = $fromDb->google->position; // 1
$data['Alibaba']['position'] = $fromDb->alibaba->position; // 4
```

If I sort the array using the `array_multisort` function as follows:

```
$sort = [];

foreach ($data as $key => $value)
    $sort[$key] = $value['position'];

array_multisort($sort, SORT_ASC, $data);
```

**Output**:

```
Array
(
    [Amazon] => 
    [Ebay] => 
    [Microsoft] => 
    [Google] => 1
    [Alibaba] => 4
)
```

**Desired output**:

```
Array
(
    [Google] => 1
    [Amazon] => 2
    [Ebay] => 3
    [Alibaba] => 4
    [Microsoft] => 5
)
```

Comment: So, you want to add numbers to those entries which are missing them, counting up in the order that they're in, obviously omitting numbers which already exist, and then sort?

Comment: Interesting question, can I ask why are you looking to do that? In which context?

Comment: Is the structure from the database always matching the static structure? As fast as I understand you want to simply fill "missing" positions with the static values?

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy I don't know if I can explain you properly but, I have all this companies listed horizontally but they might not be in the database (they are hard-coded). When the user decides to fill some information about one of them is when the row is gonna get created in the DB. The user can then decide to move the position of the company although the other companies do not exist in the database.

Comment: @Linesofcode I see I see. Well it was fun finding a solution for this one anyway :) Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filling in the missing values before doing a simple `usort`:

```
$data = [
    'Amazon'    => ['position' => null],
    'Google'    => ['position' => 1],
    'Ebay'      => ['position' => null],
    'Microsoft' => ['position' => null],
    'Alibaba'   => ['position' => 4]
];

// Find existing positions.
$positions = array_filter(array_column($data, 'position'));
$i = 1;

foreach ($data as &$comp) {
    if ($comp['position']) {
        // Element already has a position, skip to next one.
        continue;
    }
    while (in_array($i, $positions)) {
        // Increment the counter until we find a value not yet taken.
        $i++;
    }
    // Assign the counter value to the current element.
    $comp['position'] = $i++;
}
unset($comp);

// Sort all values with a simple comparison function.
uasort($data, function ($a, $b) { return $a['position'] <=> $b['position']; });
```

Somewhat fancier:

```
// Compute the *missing* positions by subtracting the existing positions
// (extracted via array_column) from the set of possible positions
// (generated with range()).
$positions = array_diff(range(1, count($data)), array_filter(array_column($data, 'position')));

// Apply the missing positions to the array elements in order
// (taking positions off the beginning with array_shift).
array_walk($data, function (&$i) use (&$positions) {
    if (!$i['position']) {
        $i['position'] = array_shift($positions);
    }
});

// Sort all values with a simple comparison function.
uasort($data, function ($a, $b) { return $a['position'] <=> $b['position']; });
```

Comment: Always with the fancy answers I see ;) Good one!

Comment: I'm sure there's an even fancier answer possible here, maybe it'll occur to me later.

Comment: Could you comment your code tho please? I had a hard time following through it.

Comment: @Islam Commented, and added a fancier version.

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
$sort = [];
$null_position = 1;
arsort($data);
foreach ($data as $key => $value){
    while(in_array($null_position,array_column($data,'position'))) {
       $null_position++;
    }
    $sort[$key] = $value['position'] ?? $null_position++;
}
asort($sort);
```

instead of

```
$sort = [];

foreach ($data as $key => $value)
    $sort[$key] = $value['position'];

array_multisort($sort, SORT_ASC, $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**.

Not sure if this is the best approach, but the output is the desired.

```
// Create three arrays to save the positions being used, etc
$itemsWithoutPosition = [];
$itemsWithPosition = [];
$listOfPositionsUsed = [];

// First grab the positions used
foreach ($original as $key => $value)
{
    if ($value['position'])
    {
        $itemsWithPosition[$key] = ['position' => $value['position']];
        array_push($listOfPositionsUsed, $value['position']);
    }
}

// Function to find the next available position
function findAvailablePosition($listOfPositionsUsed)
{
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++)
    {
        if (in_array($i, $listOfPositionsUsed))
            continue;

        return $i;
    }
}

// Loop through the items that do not have position set
foreach ($original as $key => $value)
{
    if (!$value['position'])
    {
        $position = findAvailablePosition($listOfPositionsUsed);
        $itemsWithoutPosition[$key] = ['position' => $position];

        array_push($listOfPositionsUsed, $position);
    }
}

// Merge both results
$result = array_merge($itemsWithPosition, $itemsWithoutPosition);

// Sort the results 
array_multisort($result, SORT_ASC);

// Voilá
Array
(
    [Google] => Array
        (
            [position] => 1
        )

    [Amazon] => Array
        (
            [position] => 2
        )

    [Ebay] => Array
        (
            [position] => 3
        )

    [Alibaba] => Array
        (
            [position] => 4
        )

    [Microsoft] => Array
        (
            [position] => 5
        )

)
```

Comment: This looks too complicated XD

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy I agree, I'm trying to see the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve it with two for loops and a temp table. The `$data_full` is the table that we'll be working on. And the `$data` is the table that'll be containing only the data coming from the database.

https://wtools.io/php-sandbox/b0hU

```
$data_full = 
[
    'Amazon'    => ['position' => null],
    'Google'    => ['position' => null],
    'Ebay'      => ['position' => null],
    'Microsoft' => ['position' => null],
    'Alibaba'   => ['position' => null]
];

$data = 
[
    'Amazon'    => ['position' => null],
    'Google'    => ['position' => null],
    'Ebay'      => ['position' => null],
    'Microsoft' => ['position' => null],
    'Alibaba'   => ['position' => null]
];

$data['Google']['position'] = 1;
$data['Alibaba']['position'] = 4;

$sort = [];

$num = 1;
foreach ($data_full as $key => $value) { // Loop through the table we're going to insert in
    foreach($data as $key2 => $value2) { // Loop through the table containing results from the DB
        if($data[$key2]['position']==$num) { // If it exists, we insert it, and increment the number by 1, and then continue the first loop
            $data_full[$key]['position'] = $data[$key2]['position'];
            $num++;
            continue 2;
        }
    }
    $data_full[$key]['position'] = $num;
    $num++;
}
var_dump($data_full);
```